# Mirth: When any error occurred in source then post processor script not executed

Tags: mirth

When any type of error occurred in source of mirth then post processor script not executed.

can any one tell me why this things happen?

**Update:**

I found that there is bug in mirth
http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/issues/browse/MIRTH-1294

so, now my question is how to handle error occurred in source.
i.e. how to know any error occurred in source.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to continue processing if there was an error.  Normally if you have an error you drop that message and continue or shutdown the entire channel if the order is important.
Setting up Alerts to email you on errors is my preferred notification.
You can build a JavaScript transformer step or reader and build your own TRY CATCH to handle errors your way.

Comment: first, i want to log any error in file and database so i wrote code in  in post processor script for logging. second, i already implemented try catch for error handling.